# Quick SELECT WHERE IN like with flag

Tags: mysql

I have a list of ids and need to check whether user with id is in DB or not in one SELECT. Like SELECT WHERE IN (). But SELECT WHERE IN () doesn't suit my needs, I need in one SELECT distinguish those ids that are in table, and those that are not, not using any loops like multiple SELECTS.  Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Can you show it with some sort of example

Comment: With just one single SELECT statement, I don’t see a way to do that in MySQL. I’d suggest creating a temporary table (which gets thrown away after your connection is closed), INSERT the ids you have into that, and then LEFT JOIN your existing user table to that.

Comment: You are write Cbroe. Its the solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but I guess you have table 1 which contains a lot of IDs, and you would like to see which ones occur in table 2 and which ones don't?

```
select   T1.ID, count(*) 'Times of occurrences in T2'
from     table 1 T1
           left outer join table 2 T2
               ON T1.ID = T2.ID
group by T1.ID
```

Comment: I dont have table 1, data just comes as list of ids.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details. Would it be a single query so a list could be hardcoded into query or you want to find general solution for any list of ids provided? How long is your list?

For single query and not very long list you can use union. On example:

```
SELECT some_value, EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM tableName WHERE user_id = some_value )
UNION ALL
SELECT other_value, EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM tableName WHERE user_id = other_value )
UNION ALL
SELECT other_value2, EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM tableName WHERE user_id = other_value2 )
UNION ALL
.....
```

If your list of ids can vary and/or consists of thousands of records it is impossible. In list you have columnar layout and you want to change it to row-level results. In MsSQL there are PIVOT, UNPIVOT clauses which can do that. In MySQL such transformation without explicit unions are impossible.